# jquery restricting numbers greater than required

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to restrict typing more than 20 numbers in a text box in jquery.
How to implement it.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h:inputText id="Actualcard" styleClass="input-text-bx"></h:inputText>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you mean 20 _numbers_ or 20 _digits_? (If the latter you don't need jQuery (or JS), just set `maxlength="20"`.)

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery to solve this problem? What would be wrong with just setting the maxlength property of the input? Also, I've edited your code block to make it readable and to fix a syntax error - please check your code in the preview screen before submitting questions!

Comment: Just use the maxlength attribute, it's supported everywhere and doesn't require any script.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#Actualcard").attr('maxlength','20');
```

For number validation:

```
$("#Actualcard").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      number: true
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Or use jQuery's `change()` http://api.jquery.com/change/, then trim the value and check it's length and use substr to keep cutting off anything longer than the length of 20. Don't use this as a security tho, the client user can still modify the outcome when submitting. +1 for this answer

Comment: @Allendar Why use such a convoluted solution when there's an attribute that solves the problem and has universal browser support?

Comment: I'm just pointing out how he can take control over the content, even tho his question only involves the maxlength. His absence of the experience of using the internals of the DOM was mainly the reason to point out the control over the input field. It never hurts to provide more info than needed so he can filter out whatever he wants from it :)

Comment: Also, if he needs to check "numbers" he might still need jQuery (or at least JavaScript) to check if all content within the maxlength of 20 are all digits.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="Actualcard" maxlength="20" value="" />
```

**JS**

```
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#your_from input[name=Actualcard]").change(function(){
        var input = trim($(this).attr('value'));

        // Check if it's not all digits
        if (!(typeof(input) == 'number' && parseInt(input) == input)) {
            // Do something with the value here
            $(this).attr('value', '0');
        }
    });
});
```

This way you can check if the input is all digits. I'm not 100% out of my head if `input[name=Actualcard]` works. Otherwise use an extra class on that input field to access it (`$("#your_from .my_digit_field")`).